# Symfony FOS editing/updating username/email

Tags: php, symfony

Hello I'm trying to make user update/editing system with symfony FOSUserBundle and I have little problem

currently I'm able to load existing username and email with following code:

```
  public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    $user = $userManager->findUserBy(array('id' => $id));

    $form = $this-> createFormBuilder($user)
      ->add('username')
      ->add('email')
      ->add('save', 'submit')
      ->getForm();

        $form->setData($user);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

    return $this->render('PRACTestBundle:Default:edit.html.twig', array('form' => $form->creaveView()));
  }
```

even though I'm able to submit form it won't save changes. Can someone help me out and tell how to do it? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this out..

```
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    $form = $this-> createFormBuilder($user)
      ->add('username')
      ->add('email')
      ->add('save', 'submit')
      ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

        return $this->render('PRACTestBundle:Default:edit.html.twig', array('form' => $form->creaveView()));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're mixing update action with edit page. I'm confused, why are you trying to update user just after loading data?

Here's how You should create controller with Show and Edit actions for currently logged user:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/ProfileController.php

If you're going to edit other user accounts, then change editAction from this URL to:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $userManager->findUserBy(array('id' => $id));

    // the rest of the stuff
    (...)
}
```

Let me know if this helps.